# Randomly extract value from list/ 1D array and index of value

Tags: python, arrays

I have an 1D array/list with 100 values from 1-20 randomly shuffled.

I would like to randomly select two of these values and the index of this value.

The indices of these values will be used to access two values in a second list.

so far I have:

```
list1=[]
for i in range (2):
a=random.sample(Values) #Values is the name of the array with shuffled values 1-100
list1.append(a) #this holds the two random values
```

at this point a holds:
a=[2,5]

These are two randomly selected values, but is there anyway to access their index? Both 2 and 5 are featured multiple times in the Values array.

I was thinking a dictionary approach might make sense:
a={2:6, 5:25}
to hold the value and the index. The indexes 6, and 25 in this case could be used to access the values in the second list.

I'm unsure how to code this, would anyone have some insight?

Comment: @coldspeed thank you for the edits :)

Comment: Why not randomly choose indices first, and then get the values by those indices?

Comment: @Georgy - i did not think of it this way- thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're interested in the indexes, tt seems easier to do the opposite: generate random indexes, then use them to retrieve the values:

```
import random
indexes = random.sample(range(len(Values)), 2) # get two random indexes
list1 = [Values[n] for n in indexes]
```

Following your example, this would return `[6, 25]` in the `indexes` variable and then retrieve the `[2, 5]` pair for the `list1` variable

Comment: i did not think of it this way - thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can sample from `range(len(Values))`:

```
list1_idx = []
list1 = []
for i in range (2):
    sampled_idx = random.sample(range(len(Values)))
    list1_idx.append(sampled_idx)
    list1.append(Values[sampled_idx])
```

Or more simply:

```
list1_idx = [random.sample(range(len(Values))) for i in range(2)]
list1 = [Values[i] for i in list1_idx]
```

Note that this will sample two elements with replacement, that is, you could get the same index twice. If you want to sample two distinct elements try:

```
list1_idx = random.sample(range(len(Values)), 2)
list1 = [Values[i] for i in list1_idx]
```